# Python - filename.replace does not change the filename

Tags: python

I Have a directory with a series of txt files and I want to replace a part of the filenames.  Here is an example of the filenames in the directory;

```
2017 Q2 txt WdCt.txt
2017 Q3 txt WdCt.txt
```

I want to replace `txt WdCt`  with `WdFreq` in each file name.  Here is the code I wrote to do this:

```
import os.path
sourcedir = 'C:/Users/Public/EnvDef/Proj/1ErnCls/IOUErnCls/Wd Ct by Qrtr/All Word Count'
os.chdir(sourcedir)
cwd = os.getcwd()
print(' 2 Working Directory is     %s' % cwd)
print(' ')
for dirPath, subdirNames, fileList in os.walk(cwd):
    for filename in fileList:
        print("Old File Name")
        print(filename)
        filename=filename.replace('txt WdCT','WdFreq')
        print ("New File Name")
        print(filename)
```

And the following is an example of the output. It appears that the script does walk through the directory and the output shows the files to be renamed as desired. However, the file names in the directory are NOT changed. I have searched online and found many examples that are like what I am trying to do but I cannot determine why my code does not make a change in the name of the files.  Any help and or suggestions will be appreciated.

Working Directory: `C:\Users\Public\EnvDef\Proj\1ErnCls\IOUErnCls\Wd Ct by Qrtr\All Word Count`

Old File Name:
`2017 Q2 txt WdCt.txt`

New File Name:
`2017 Q2 WdFreq.txt`

Comment: You would have to call `os.rename()` with the arguments: 1) the original path w/ filename, and 2) the updated path w/ filename.

Comment: `filename=filename.replace('txt WdCT','WdFreq')` All that does is modify a string, no? As an aside, I would really recommend using pathlib for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `filename=filename.replace('txt WdCT','WdFreq')` only changes the string representing the file name. You then need to rename the file using `os.rename` or  `shutil.move`

```
import os
sourcedir = 'C:/Users/Public/EnvDef/Proj/1ErnCls/IOUErnCls/Wd Ct by Qrtr/All Word Count'
os.chdir(sourcedir)
cwd = os.getcwd()
print(' 2 Working Directory is     %s' % cwd)
print(' ')
for dirPath, subdirNames, fileList in os.walk(cwd):
    for filename in fileList:
        os.rename(os.path.join(dirPath, filename), os.path.join(dirPath, filename.replace('txt WdCT','WdFreq')))
```

Comment: Apologies for not responding sooner but I was overtaken by events.  Thanks to you all for the good guidance, It is much appreciated.

Comment: Please vote the answer that helped you and mark this as solved

Answer (score 1):

I second @mechanical_meat's suggestion, you would have to use the method `os.rename(source file, destination file)`. Also, if you are interested on filenames from only a specific directory, I would suggest to take a look at this method `os.listdir(directory path)` since `os.walk()` iterates through all files and sub-directories under the specified directory.

A modified version of your code using `os.listdir()` -

```
import os
sourcedir = '<your directory path>'
os.chdir(sourcedir)
path = os.getcwd()
filenames = os.listdir(path)

for filename in filenames:
    os.rename(filename, filename.replace("txt WdCt.txt", "WdFreq.txt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

List of changes:

- Replaced the use of % string formatting, as was done in Python 2.6.
- Replaced os.path with the great [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).
- Changed variable names to follow proper style conventions.
- Removed the superfluous (at best) changing of the working directory.

Code:

```py
import pathlib

source_dir = pathlib.Path("/Users/alexandercecile/Documents/Projects/AdHoc/resources/temp")

for curr_path in source_dir.iterdir():
    print(f"{curr_path=}")
    new_path = curr_path.rename(source_dir.joinpath(curr_path.name.replace("txt WdCt", "WdFreq")))
    print(f"{new_path=}\n")
```

Output:

```
curr_path=PosixPath('/Users/alexandercecile/Documents/Projects/AdHoc/resources/temp/2017 Q2 txt WdCt.txt')
new_path=PosixPath('/Users/alexandercecile/Documents/Projects/AdHoc/resources/temp/2017 Q2 WdFreq.txt')

curr_path=PosixPath('/Users/alexandercecile/Documents/Projects/AdHoc/resources/temp/2017 Q3 txt WdCt.txt')
new_path=PosixPath('/Users/alexandercecile/Documents/Projects/AdHoc/resources/temp/2017 Q3 WdFreq.txt')
```